# Webform how to pass that SUBMITTED TO value through hidden field in a form submission?

Tags: 8, webforms

In Drupal 8 I have created a job application form using webform module. I have created a Jobs content type and created few jobs like Job A, Job B, Job C and in each job the same form is used.

When we submit the job application for different jobs and check the results on submissions page

admin/structure/webform/manage/apply_for_job/results/submissions

it shows us the SUBMITTED TO column under which it shows for which job this submission is.

I want to know how to pass that SUBMITTED TO value through hidden field in a form submission?

Comment: What version of Webform is it?

Comment: must be 8.5 beta